# Detect Click on Browser

Tags: javascript

How to detect click (including browser's back button) events using javascript?

Comment: +1 for a terribly worded question.

Comment: Two suggestions that will help you get better answers:

1. Re-word your question so that it's clear what it is you're talking about. Be as specific as you can.

2. Go back and accept answers for the 22 questions you've asked previously. People will be more likely to answer your questions if they know they're going to be recognized for it.

Comment: No...! Javascript is innocent, don't sue it. :p

Comment: JavaScript *is* innocent. And JavaScript *will not rest* until the real event is detected and brought to justice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can detect clicks inside the page with a simple `click` event handler:

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    // Compensate for IE<9's non-standard event model
    //
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement;

    alert('clicked on '+target.tagName);
};
```

It is impossible for web-page script detect clicks outside the page such as the back button and other browser chrome, for good security reasons. You would have to be part of a browser extension to do this.

Comment: +1 Bobince, you give great answers to not so great questions!