# Refresh iframe when screen is clicked

Tags: javascript

Not too familiar with javascript. I have done some searching and am having trouble implementing this code into my current project.

Basically want to refresh the iframe when the screen is clicked. I currently have this code:

```
document.getElementById('').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

I want to integrate it into this code:

```
    $(".launch").loadthis({ direction: "left", connect: true });
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean when the screen is clicked? Anywhere in the browser window?

Comment: @meewok yes, correct or alternatively when clicking outside ending another javascript I am running that is .launch

Comment: If the iframe is clicked and is from an external domain, it cannot inform the hosting window that it has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues that are unclear in your question.

**1) What do you mean when you say "Screen is clicked" ?**

- Anywhere in the open browser window?
- Anywhere in the open browser window including the iframe?

**2) Is your IFRAME 100% of the width and height of the browser window?**

*Regardless, below I break down your problem and hopefully give you a solution...*

**How do we refresh a webpage?**

You can refresh a webpage using:

```
location.reload(true);
```

**How do we refresh an iframe?**

You may refresh an IFRAME using the code here:
[Refresh an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244877/refresh-an-iframe)

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
document.getElementById("myiframe").src = "http://www.google.com?"+(+new Date());
```

**How do we detect the click?**

You can use the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622026/1688441

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    // Compensate for IE<9's non-standard event model
    //
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement;

    alert('clicked on '+target.tagName);
};
```

**Remaining issues:**

***What happens if user clicks within IFRAME?***

If the user clicks within the IFRAME, and we control the code of the IFRAME we can have a click listener within the HTML/JAVASCRIPT of the IFRAME and trigger a refresh.

If we have different domains, due to security reasons there is not much that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListeneder("click", windowClickHandler);

function windowClickHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript);